# Getting CPU statistics from libvirt

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu-usage, libvirt

Is it possible using the python bindings of libvirt to get the running, waiting and ready time of a VM from the host?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "waiting" and "ready" time, but whatever that is, I believe it is possible using the getCPUStats() function called on a domain object.  The docstrings of that function follows:

> **getCPUStats(total, flags=0)**
>
> Extracts CPU statistics for a running domain. On success it will return a list of data of dictionary type. If boolean total is False or 0, the first element of the list refers to CPU0 on the host, second element is CPU1, and so on. The format of data struct is as follows:
>
> [{cpu_time:xxx}, {cpu_time:xxx}, ...]
>
> If it is True or 1, it returns total domain CPU statistics in the format of
>
> [{cpu_time:xxx, user_time:xxx, system_time:xxx}]